# GlobalSecondary index in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have to create a Global Secondary Index in Dynamo Db. My Primary table structure is below -

```
{
  "primaryId" : "1234" //HashKey
   "dummy1" : "kkd",
   "dummy2" : "ddd",
   "secondObj": [{
                 "secondObjId" : "1234",
                 "name" : "1234",
                },
                {
                 "secondObjId" : "12345",
                 "name" : "12345",
                }]

}
```

Now i have to create GlobalSecondary Index based on "secondObjId" as a hashkey. is it possible to create?

I have created it using AWS console but its showing item count 0 and if i am creating GlobalSecondaryIndex using "dumy1" then its showing proper item count.

So my query is that is it possible to create a GlobalSecondayIndex based on a attribute from DynamoDBDocument?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes can be built only on top-level JSON attributes. In addition, range keys must be scalar values in DynamoDB (one of String, Number, Binary, or Boolean).